# Updating store after initialization for AlpineJS doesn't work

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

To initialize a store I have

```js
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.store('selectedInput', 0)
})
```

But when I do this in a function further down, it doesn't update `selectedInput`:

```js
function example() {
  Alpine.store('selectedInput', 3)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using an example from the documentation website  - https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-store

```
Alpine.store('darkMode', {
    on: false,

    toggle() {
        this.on = ! this.on
    }
})
```

`darkMode` is the name of your store.
`on` is a property
`toggle` is a function

So in your case, it should look something like this -

```
Alpine.store('nameOfStore', {
    selectedInput: 0,

    example() {
        this.selectedInput = 3
    }
})
```

You can replace `nameOfStore` with anything you like.

To call the function, you will do this -
`$store.nameOfStore.example()`

Comment: Yep that's in the docs. At the bottom of that page there's also `Alpine.store('darkMode', false)`, so you can set a value directly it seems. As per my post this actually works on initialization, just not further down in the file when I want to use that line to set the variable to a different value.

Comment: @eskimo ok... inside example() do this `this.$store.selectedInput = 3`